# Are there capabilities in the Rust standard library to download a file from a URL

Tags: url, download, io, rust

I'm new to Rust.

I have written a few Hello World programs and the program I usually try to write next interacts with the web in some way. I usually try downloading a file. I figured I could learn something about the Rust "net" and "io" areas. But I have not been able to find an example of how to do this in Rust.

Are there any capabilities in the Standard Library to download a file from a URL?

Comment: Depending on what you want to learn exactly, since Rust features TCP handling, you could actually implement basic file download by yourself I guess... it would be a bit low-level.

Answer (score 10):

Rust's standard library has no HTTP functionality. You will have to use a third-party library like [curl](https://github.com/carllerche/curl-rust) or [hyper](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper) or implement something yourself.